# Django: log json params of request on exception

Tags: python, json, django, logging

Is there a built-in way to log request params on django error, if they are pasesed as json? Like it's done in RubyOnRails for example.

Say, if view action fails with an exeption, it's request and params are added to log.

What I get in error email from django: `POST:<QueryDict: {}>`

What would've been nice to get: `POST:{"id":4,action:"status"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure  of logging handler, that sends emails to include html :

```
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
           'level': 'ERROR',
           'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
           'include_html': True,
        }
}
```

All data will be there. That's the only way to see json POST data, that I've came up to;

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Django takes care of this automatically. If you have `DEBUG=True` in your settings, you'll see a nicely formatted traceback with full context and all the request details. Otherwise, Django will send you an email with the error details (including the HTTP request). You can also configure the logging settings to write error messages to your server logs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/error-reporting/

Comment: I've edited my question, it happend I had problems with json